# Is it ok to ask beginner level question?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am new to using vim. So I think my questions will be in the beginners level only. Should I wait till public beta to ask my questions? Will asking beginner level question impede the site from being launched?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

"beginner-level" is not a particularly useful classification here. The criteria you should apply, *especially* during the private beta, is:

### "Does this question require an expert to answer?"

How do you, as a beginner, know whether your question meets that requirement? Simple: **do your research!**

- **Have you read [a "getting started" guide](https://www.google.com/search?q=getting%20started%20vim) for your editor of choice?** If you haven't spent 10 minutes doing that, don't expect someone with years of experience to put much thought into answering your question.
- **Have you [*searched*](https://www.google.com/search?q=vim%20syntax%20highlighting) for the answer first?** It's ok if you did and simply weren't able to find an answer you could understand - but use that experience to explain the sort of assistance you require.

Plenty of experts enjoy answering "beginner" questions, but few enjoy answering questions that are unclear or have already been answered - and answered *well* - dozens of times before. In particular, this site currently sits in the shadow of [an *extensive* library of high-quality questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vim) - slavishly recreating them without adding anything new and useful isn't a reputation y'all want to be cultivating, *particularly* during the private beta.

Comment: Nice. We shouldn't forget that even the simplest solution may be hard to find if you don't know what exactly you are looking for. So "simple" questions are fine, stupid questions are not.

Answer (score 8):

The site will eventually welcome beginner-level questions.  This is our opportunity to make some exemplar beginner-level questions to get the community started properly.

Comment: I don't so much agree with this way of putting it. We should, from the _very beginning_, to show to express that no research effort is no research effort. The private beta should not be flooded with very simple or even stupid questions.

Comment: @yo' That's why I said "examplar" — we should show how to write beginner-level questions that are _good quality_.

Comment: ah ok, that's the message I didn't get from your post, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

I think beginner questions are fine. I think this site should aim to be the goto site for anyone with questions about Vi/Vim, and as such it should contain answers to any and all (on-topic) questions that someone might ask about Vi/Vim, and not only the questions for which answers cannot already be found elsewhere on the web.